# change email addres with http request

Tags: webform-civicrm

using the rest API, I am able to change 'normal' fields with a single occurence. But I can't figure out what I should do to change the first email addressl.

Civicrm only accepts post requests to do a database change. If I put in the post parameter hash something like

```
{ :contact_type => 'Individual',
:id => 14330,
:job_title => 'workaholic',
'email[0][email]' => 'testaccount@gmail.com',
:entity => 'Contact' }))
```

the corresponding record is changed (job title is changed) and the email address is *added*. But not replaced. Do I miss some required parameter to make this work?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can best be done through the Email object.
Find the collection of Email objects having contact_id 14330. Take the first object and use its id to change it:

issue a post request with

```
{ :entity=> 'Email',
   :id=> *EMAILID*,
   :email=> 'NEWADDRES@gmail.com',
   :action => 'create'
}
```